# WSO2 with OSB11g Issue :CannotCreate Null value provided: initial value

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, osb, oracle-soa

Please help me i am stuck with the issue.

i made a UDDI Registry with WSO2 Governance Registry, I am able successfully to publish the OSB proxy to WSO2 Governance Registry, published service is visible in WSO2 Governance Registry, but when i am trying to import same service in OSB from the UDDI WSO2 Governance Registry.

**Here is the error message over OSB Console:CannotCreate Null value provided: initial value**

**OSB Server Logs:**

OSB Server Complete Logs:

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <0515430f871fd517:19c2202:14efd42a60d:-8000-0000000000000111> <1438769939970>  

     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>  <> <0515430f871fd517:19c2202:14efd42a60d:-8000-0000000000000131> <1438769977434>

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null value provided: initial value
    at com.bea.wli.config.task.impl.SessionedTask.assertNotNull(SessionedTask.java:293)
    at com.bea.wli.config.task.impl.CreateResourceTask.(CreateResourceTask.java:44)
    at com.bea.wli.config.task.impl.CreateResourceTask.createResource(CreateResourceTask.java:82)
    at com.bea.wli.config.task.impl.CreateResourceTask.createResource(CreateResourceTask.java:66)
    at com.bea.wli.sb.uddi.importservices.ALSRServices.importServices(ALSRServices.java:1855)
    at com.bea.wli.sb.uddi.management.configuration.UDDIConfiguration.importServices(UDDIConfiguration.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.alsb.console.support.ConsoleSideMBeanInvocationHandler.__invoke(ConsoleSideMBeanInvocationHandler.java:113)
    at com.bea.alsb.console.support.ConsoleSideMBeanInvocationHandler.invoke(ConsoleSideMBeanInvocationHandler.java:71)
    at $Proxy209.importServices(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.alsb.console.uddi.UDDIImportHelper.importServices(UDDIImportHelper.java:487)
    at com.bea.alsb.console.uddi.pageflow.uddiimport.UDDIImport.importServices(UDDIImport.java:473)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:879)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:91)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
    at com.bea.alsb.console.common.base.SBConsoleRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(SBConsoleRequestProcessor.java:91)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
    at com.bea.alsb.console.common.base.SBConsoleRequestProcessor.process(SBConsoleRequestProcessor.java:194)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:159)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:416)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:135)
    at com.bea.alsb.console.common.base.SBConsoleActionServlet.doGet(SBConsoleActionServlet.java:50)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1129)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:687)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:142)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:107)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:160)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:389)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:199)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:253)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
    at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:131)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

> 

Comment: Help me please WSO2 champs, i am stuck with this issue.